# Did Galileo offer an explanation why his law of falling bodies is independent of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, history, free-fall

Naively, (and endorsed by Aristotle) one expects heavier things to fall more quickly, [Galileo Galilei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei#Falling_bodies) showed in the early modern period, that in fact this is not correct, and that in fact how they fell as independent of mass (if air resistance remained negligible).

Did he offer an explanation of this observation?

Comment: Yes, but I take objection to calling Aristotle "naive". It was Galileo who was naive--- his naivete is what makes modern science successful, since we all are naive in the same way today.

Comment: I'm not calling Aristotle naive, but the hypothetical layman. I'm saying that Aristotle claimed that heavier objects fell more quickly than lighter ones.

Comment: I am saying that thousands of naive laymen probably knew Aristotle was full of crap for centuries, just by dropping heavy and light objects next to each other. Aristotle was a _poweful influential moron_, the naive laymen (this includes Galileo) are the ones who were right, then as now as always. The difference between Galileo and the others is that Galileo was willing to endure persecution to publish his findings in Italian.

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28097/2451) Philosophy.SE question, which is now migrated to Physics.SE as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes--- he argued as follows in *Dialogue concerning the Two Principal World Systems*: suppose you tie a heavy object to a light one with a rope, would the light object fall slower and retard the heavy object, or would the heavy and light object together be a heavy object that falls more quickly? He concludes that neither: they both fall at the same rate.

This type of philosophical argument is persuasive, but Galileo always backs it up with naive experiments, and naive measurements. Aristotle's views are almost never "naive" in this way, and because of this they are almost never correct! Aristotle was writing for elites, and his pontifications are designed to be *erudite and convincing*, they are not designed to be correct, or else he would have done the experiment too. His books are ancient coffee-table books, they have no academic value.

Anyone who did the experiment would have seen Galileo is right, it is the non-naive arguments about the medium being the cause of the motion, and the impelling motive forces and desires of objects, that make Aristotle's blatherings both the opposite of naive, and the opposite of correct.

Comment: Do you know whether any of the ancient atomists (greek, indian, islamic) made a similar argument?

Comment: But medium can be the cause of motion: isn't spacetime a medium & the cause of gravity? Of course it does depend on exactly what you mean by medium, early 20C physics dropped the idea of a *mechanical* medium for light for the *field* medium. As for the *desires* of objects, is it any better to call it a law of *attaction*?

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Nobody in ancient times that survives, but it's possible. I would have expected Archimedes to mention it if it existed, he doesn't. The medium is not the cause of motion, the field is not a "medium" in A's sense, objects don't have tendencies. None of his stuff has value, it is elitist garbage, please don't read modern things into it, it's unsalvagable. His argument for a medium was an argument against Democritus's atoms, and the argument that speed increases to infinity in vacuum, so nature fills all void with stuff ("Nature abhors a vacuum"). This was stupid garbage even then.

Comment: Well I see the Aristotelian argument as follows: all inertia is due to viscosity (he also argues that all free moving bodies will stop sometimes). This is wrong, but it makes sense and viscosity contributes to the speed of falling objects so that the more massive ones indeed fall faster than lighter ones if they have the same shape.

Comment: @Anixx: This is a modern reinterpretation of Aristotle. What he _actually_ says is that if you have an object, it's motion is intrinsically an interaction of object and medium, and happens faster as the medium is more tenuous. Not because of viscosity, but because it is pushing the medium out of the way! Note that in modern theories the "pushing of a fluid out of the way" does not create friction without internal viscosity, so that moving a ball in He4 at slow velocities is frictionless, even though you push He4 out of the way. Aristotle continues that if the medium is infinitely dilute...

Comment: Aristotelean disbelief in void is also correct after all: there is no place in universe that is not filled with photons and as such any fast moving object will sooner of later slow down due to light pressure.

Comment: the speed will become infinite. This leads him to conclude that air is about 10 times less dense than water, and that if you make air ten times less dense still, things will move ten times faster (he isn't so mathematical, but that's the idea). Then vacuum is impossible, because stuff will rush into a vacuum infinitely fast the instant it forms. This is complete gibberish, not just from our vantage point, but even back then, when you could see by moving your hand that water is about 100 times more dense than air, and that tenuous media do not make infinite speed.

Comment: @Anixx: again, you are interpreting Aristotle wrong. The argument is not the third law, that you can't achieve absolute zero, but that space does not make sense unless it is filled with a continuous matter medium that allows motion of things only by displacing other things, so that no two things are at the same point at the same time (one of Aristotle's "laws"). His arguments are like a stopped clock, and the fact that you can make them right twice a day using viscosity and 3rd law does not make them any less worthless. To appreciate just how worthless, read Aristotle, not commentators.

Comment: Well Ron, superfluid mediums are very rare and even in the case of superfluid helium onece you reach certain critical speed, the viscosity appears. Aristotle's assumption are certainly wrong but they may sense if one assumes that all inertia is due to medium resistance and there is no natural limit on speed.

Comment: "no two things are at the same point at the same time" - this law is currently known as Pauli exclusion principle. It is known now not to be universally valid. It is valid for all substance though.

Comment: @Anixx: It isn't pauli exclusion, because a proton and a neutron can be at the same point, and Aristotle applied it to _different_ objects, not identical ones. If we had two independent electron fields with independent nuclei, matter made out of one electron field could interpenetrate matter made out of the other. Aristotle is not giving a correct anything, and this type of fitting the modern ideas to the ancient gibberish is the annoying things that modern Aristotelians do. These people exist, they are in philosophy departments, and they are annoying to no end.

Comment: @Anixx: Regarding resistance, I read Aristotle expecting this point of view, which is how it is presented in modern times. This is not Aristotle's point of view. He sees the medium pushing out of the way as the important thing that defines motion. Even in a non-superfluid, the resistance is not due to the pushing of fluid out of the way, but to friction inside the fluid, and it varies differently depending on your speed in a way that is only approximately Aristotelian (proportional to the amount of stuff shoved out of the way) in the limit of very fast velocities in a very non-viscous material

Comment: @Anixx: The only point of Aristotle's blathering about motion is to deny atomism and geocentrism, the central scientific breakthroughs of his time. The atomic ideas, and democracy, were due to democritus. Aristotle is out to justify aristocracy and villify democracy. He wants to discredit certain materialistic conceptions due to the scientists of his day, and also Plato's spiritual conceptions, and substitute his own authority-loving materialistic stuff. He is a piker, and his ideas only became influential because they reenforced authority structure, and he made friends with Alex the great.

Comment: Well yes, neutron can pass through proton but the fact that two macroscopic bodies cannot occupy the same place is due to Pauli principle, because all bodies are filled with electrons. I want to note that nobody before Aristotle mentioned the fact that subtance bodies cannot occupy the same place, which is in fact a law of nature.

Comment: LOL I doubt very much that democracy is due to Democritus and aristocracy is due to Aristotle :-) In any case, Aristotelean argument against heliocentric system (that Earth would stop moving) is quite valid. The only reason why it does not work is because the interplanetary medium has much less density than air (which was supposed to fill all space at the time). Still the argument works but at much greater time scale: Earth will stop its motion around Sun sooner or later due to medium resistanse and tidal forces.

Comment: @Anixx: You miss the main point, that Aristotle considered it impossible that such a medium so much less tenuous than air can exist. He believed the air would be sucked out of the Earth into the interstellar medium at infinite speed, until the density was uniform. This is his law of motion--- matter expands to fill all space. The names are coincidental, but Democritus advocated democracy and Aristotle advocated aristocracy. You are linking modern ideas to Aristotle anachronistically, why would you do this? Have you read Aristotle? His ideas do not fit into a modern framework.

Comment: Well the air from the Moon is in fact sucked into interstellar medium. Aristotle knew that there are mediums of different density but he indeed did now know that interstellar meduium has SO little density. He possibly assumed that air had constant density as water did. By the way, Aristotle's law of motion in a dense medium is known now as Stokes law.

Comment: Take this to [chat] if it is to continue, please.